# Can I use this simple try catch syntax?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, try-catch

I'm using asp.net mvc 5.

I used :

```
try
{
   // some code of any type
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ViewBag.error = e.Message;
}
```

I'm not using throw keyword and only I want to show the error in the view.

is my syntax correct?

thanks.

Comment: are you getting any errors? I dont understand what the question is

Comment: Whether you *should* catch all possible exceptions and throw away all information other than the message is, of course, a completely different question.

Comment: I don't see any errors besides missing `;` at the end of `ViewBag.error = e.Message` .

Comment: Now you have a very technical error message, which possibly is incomplete since you do not capture any inner exceptions. Now, what will you do with this message? Display it to your users? You should log it, take countermeasures or display a user friendly message.

Comment: ok thank you @Peter Bons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should normally not just catch any type of `exception` like this. This can cause your program to go into undefined states. You should make it more Specific for example only catch `SocketExceptions`. Yes, this might cause your program to crash if an unhandled exception appears but a user that has to restart an application might be less bad than an application that causes damage to a system because it does things it was not supposed to be. 
Imagine you have a function that builds a string which is a path to a directory. You get a parse exception and now your program will delete...what? you cant tell for sure. But if you in your `catch` handled the parse exception specifically you can be sure that you reacted right to the situation

```
try
{
   //some some SocketStuff
}
catch (SocketException e)
{
    //cancel network operation
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
    //use default string
}
```

Your approach with catching any type of `Exception` should only be used if you know the code that's in it can not cause any damage at all, for example, GUI-Related code that will not cause severe problems in the long run.

Comment: Good answer. i will use it. thank you

Comment: @HosseinBabaei if this answers your question please mark it as the answer for others to find

Comment: ok. can you explain me to usage of (throw) keyword in the catch section ? thanks. @Denis Schaf

Comment: @HosseinBabaei take a look at this link :)
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use this for exception handling.

Also, you can define different types of exception for handling exceptions dynamically

Below is the code for how we can access it in CSHTML.

```
@if (ViewBag.Error != null)
{
    <h3 style="color:red">@ViewBag.Error</h3>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! This syntax is correct. You can show the error in the page using below code.

```
@if (ViewBag.Error != null)
{
   <h4 style="color:#e74c3c">@ViewBag.Error</h4>
}
```